# Allow access to website only to specific IP's using JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ip

Could you please give me hint or sample code for restricting access to website to only specific IP addresses using no more or less than JS / jQuery?

I found a lot of examples for other methods like htaccess or so, but not for JS

Comment: Javascript code only runs after the user already loaded the site.

Comment: `if ( user != me ) return;`

Comment: It doesn't have to be secured. I just don't want to show that page to "every day" web users.

Comment: If you're hiding anything sensitive based on IP, then you'll probably have to go with server-side checks. Will it be bad/dangerous if a user messes with some javascript and accesses your IP-restricted page, or is it just to make it look different?

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this with client side code. If you want to use JavaScript then you have to use server side JavaScript (e.g. via Node.js, Classic ASP w/JScript, [etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_server-side_JavaScript_solutions)).

The specifics of how you get the IP address will depend on the server side framework you use. Typically you would be able to retrieve it by accessing a method or property of whatever object represents.

(If you aren't using server side JS already, you probably should look towards a more mainstream solution such as the ones you've already found).

Comment: What about something like this:
var allowedAddresses = ['127.0.0.1']; 
if (!currentAddress in allowedAddresses) document.body.innerHTML = '';

Comment: @DavorB — Turn JS off and the content is available. View source and the content is available. Use a text browser and the content is available. You can't make the client censor itself.

Comment: ohh that's right. Didn't think of that. Thanks for note

Answer (score 0):

JS is clientside - you cannot restrict them from seeing the page... using the page.

What kind of backend are you running? It is trivial through an endpoint.